# How to remove delay when app engaged after being idle

Tags: android, cordova

We deploy our Cordova app on an Android 7.1 device (kiosk).

We have set the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` as per [Stop my app from sleeping (Cordova/Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107778/stop-my-app-from-sleeping-cordova-android).

When the app has been idle for, say an hour, the initial interaction (button touch) has a 1-2 second delay.

Any ideas how to keep the CPU 100% active 100% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the wake lock, you could run a foreground service and have it run something in a continuous loop in a separate thread in order to keep the CPU active. For example

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(10000); //sleep 10 seconds
                //do anything
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```